# advanced calculus by Lynn Harold Loomis and Shlomo Sternberg - question 4.12

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

> Supposing that $T$ is the identity on $N$ and on $V/N$, and setting $R=I-T$, show that there exists a $K\in Hom(V/N, V)$ such that $R=K\circ\pi$. Show that for any coset $A$ of $N$ the action of $T$ on $A$ can be viewed as translation through $K(A)$. that is, if $\xi\in A$ and $\eta = K(A)$, then $T(\xi)=\xi+\eta$

This question is taken from advanced calculus by Lynn Harold Loomis and Shlomo Sternberg

The book designate $\overline{\alpha}=\alpha+N$ and $\pi(\alpha)=\overline{\alpha}$ (V is assumed to be a vector space and $N$ is a subspace of $V$)

For the first part, I have shown that $K(\overline{\alpha})=R(\alpha)$ is well defined.

The second part:
We know that $R=I-T\Rightarrow T=I-R=I-K\circ\pi$
Therefore $T(\xi)=\xi-K(\overline{\xi})=\xi-K(A)=\xi-\eta\neq\xi+\eta$
Is this a mistake in the book or am I missing something?

Comment: What is $I$ here?

Comment: The identity transformation. i.e $I(x)=x$

Comment: So you're saying $I$ is the identity on $V$, and $T$ merely the identity on $N$, i.e. $I|_N = T$?

Comment: yes. the problem also states that T is the identity on $V/N$ which is to my understanding says that $T[\overline{\alpha}]=\overline{\alpha}$

Comment: I think you are right. The plus in $\xi+\eta$ should be a minus. The authors probably defined $R$ as $T-I$ at first (as they did in problem 4.10), changed the definition to $I-T$ afterwards but forgot to modify the conclusion. The definition $R=T-I$ might also read $R=I-T$.

Comment: My guess is that it is indeed a typo. Maybe they're just abusing notation a bit, and meant to say something like $T(\xi) = \xi+\tilde{\eta}$, where $\tilde{\eta} := -\eta$.